# MySQL , How to give output of UNION to WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following SQL

```
SELECT tsd.ID
FROM test_series_details tsd
WHERE tsd.DIV_ID =1 
  AND tsd.END_DATE > NOW()
  AND tsd.ID NOT IN 
        ((SELECT tsr.TEST_ID
        FROM  test_series_results tsr
        WHERE tsr.STUDENT_ID=3)
    UNION 
        (SELECT tsrlv.TEST_ID
        FROM test_series_restore_log_viewer tsrlv
        WHERE tsrlv.STUDENT_ID=3
        GROUP BY tsrlv.TEST_ID))
```

I have tested below part of query and it is working,

```
(SELECT tsr.TEST_ID
        FROM  test_series_results tsr
        WHERE tsr.STUDENT_ID=3)
    UNION 
        (SELECT tsrlv.TEST_ID
        FROM test_series_restore_log_viewer tsrlv
        WHERE tsrlv.STUDENT_ID=3
        GROUP BY tsrlv.TEST_ID)
```

But how to give output of this UNION to IN condition?

ERROR IS AS follows

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'UNION     (SELECT tsrlv.TEST_ID    FROM
>   test_series_restore_log_viewer tsrlv    ' at line 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to write this is as two separate clauses:

```
SELECT tsd.ID
FROM test_series_details tsd
WHERE tsd.DIV_ID = 1 AND
      tsd.END_DATE > NOW() AND
      tsd.ID NOT IN (SELECT tsr.TEST_ID
                     FROM test_series_results tsr
                     WHERE tsr.STUDENT_ID = 3
                    ) AND
      tsd.ID NOT IN (SELECT tsrlv.TEST_ID
                     FROM test_series_restore_log_viewer tsrlv
                     WHERE tsrlv.STUDENT_ID = 3
                    );
```

This allows the engine to take advantage of indexes on the two tables.  In addition, the `GROUP BY` is not necessary (either when written this way or in your original formulation).

For performance -- and just in case the ids in the subqueries could ever be `NULL` -- I would be inclined to write this using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT tsd.ID
FROM test_series_details tsd
WHERE tsd.DIV_ID = 1 AND
      tsd.END_DATE > NOW() AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM test_series_results tsr
                  WHERE tsr.STUDENT_ID = 3 and tsr.TEST_ID = tsd.ID
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM test_series_restore_log_viewer tsrlv
                  WHERE tsrlv.STUDENT_ID = 3 and tsrlv.TEST_ID = tsd.ID
                 );
```

The best indexes for this query are:  `test_series_results(test_id, student_id)` and `test_series_restore_log_viewer(test_id, student_id)` and `test_series_details(DIV_ID, end_date, id)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `LEFT JOIN` as below

```
SELECT tsd.ID
FROM test_series_details tsd
LEFT JOIN ((SELECT tsr.TEST_ID
        FROM  test_series_results tsr
        WHERE tsr.STUDENT_ID=3)
        UNION 
        (SELECT tsrlv.TEST_ID
        FROM test_series_restore_log_viewer tsrlv
        WHERE tsrlv.STUDENT_ID=3
        GROUP BY tsrlv.TEST_ID)) AS T on T.TEST_ID = tsd.ID 
WHERE tsd.DIV_ID =1 
  AND tsd.END_DATE > NOW()
  AND T.TEST_ID is null
```

Answer (score 1):

How about now -

```
SELECT tsd.ID
FROM test_series_details tsd
WHERE 
tsd.DIV_ID =1 
AND tsd.END_DATE > NOW()
AND tsd.ID NOT IN (
   select TEST_ID from (
     (
        SELECT tsr.TEST_ID
        FROM  test_series_results tsr
        WHERE tsr.STUDENT_ID=3
     )
     UNION 
     (
        SELECT tsrlv.TEST_ID
        FROM test_series_restore_log_viewer tsrlv
        WHERE tsrlv.STUDENT_ID=3
        GROUP BY tsrlv.TEST_ID
     )
    )x
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  SELECT tsd.ID
  FROM test_series_details tsd
  WHERE tsd.DIV_ID =1 
  AND tsd.END_DATE > NOW()
  AND tsd.ID NOT IN 
  (
      select  TEST_ID from (
       SELECT tsr.TEST_ID
       FROM  test_series_results tsr
       WHERE tsr.STUDENT_ID=3

       UNION 

       SELECT tsrlv.TEST_ID
       FROM test_series_restore_log_viewer tsrlv
       WHERE tsrlv.STUDENT_ID=3
       GROUP BY tsrlv.TEST_ID   
     )as alias 
   )
```